# Does anyone know what this pipe is in an HVAC system?

Tags: hvac

[image]

In a new rental (one story, approx 1400 sq ft), one of the bedrooms was not as cool as the other two. I noticed air flowing from the attic door in the ceiling, so went to investigate. The pipe (thin plastic, not PVC) circled had air flowing out of it. It has a flap on the end, so the more air that flows the flap would open. It was strong enough of a flow to blow the insulation around it away. The A/C was running at the time. I went and looked a couple hours later and the flap was closed, so air was not flowing thru it, but A/C was still running. This isn't a dampener, as it is just an open pipe and you do not set the flap to a certain position. This is just an open pipe that seems to have air flowing out of it at certain times. Does anyone know what this pipe is? I don't have any specs on the HVAC system, as I'm just renting.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a vent pipe that would be hooked up to a ventilation fan in the bathroom.  If the bathroom door was closed, you might get quite a bit of air loss out of that pipe, but when the door is open, there wouldn't be as much pressure to push the A/C out of that room.

Those ventilation fans are not supposed to vent into the attic because their supposed purpose is to remove humid air, but incorrect installations are pretty common.

Comment: Our builder did just that, and when the house A/C is running, the attic tubing behaves in a similar manner. Dampers are not going to be placed in an attic, as such devices are engineered to be easily accessible. If the pipe is left open and you run your bathroom (or other room fan) to cause moist air to enter your attic, it will become the dampener and reduce the effectiveness of your insulation. Note: damper restricts airflow, dampener causes things to become damp (wet).

Comment: This makes sense after hearing these two explanations. The room that wasn't cooling had the ceiling fan on full blast to try to keep the room cooler. This room has a 1/2 bath and this tube could have been in this bathroom coming from the vent. I will double check to see if this is the case. Thanks!

Comment: @kricca, At this point its just an educated guess.  You will have to verify.  Check it out with the fan on and off, etc.